# Getting error using ContactManager Sample

Tags: android

I have created some contacts data in the emulator. When I run the ContactManager sample app downloaded from the Android site, I get an error. Specifically, when trying to add a Contact through the app, I get a NullPointerException.

I think it is because the "Target Accounts" spinner on the scree is not getting populated, and hence I cannot select a Target Account before adding a contact.

Has anyone run across this problem or has any clues on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked and I get the same error. The code just assumes there is an existing account. You should create an account yourself from settings, then try rerunning the demo app.

Comment: I cannot create accounts on the emulator. Here's what I tried: Settings/Accounts and sync/Add account --> entered username@gmail.com & password ---> Clicked on Next ----> Getting error: "Setup could not finish : Unable to open connection to the server"